# phpcomplete show protected function and variables in suggestion

Tags: php, vim, autocomplete, vim-plugin

I installed phpcomplete and YouCompleteMe in vim. YCM work well for class functions and variable but not show completion for any built in function. 
Then I  install phpcomplete ( as i read it also provide support for built in function ) but it after installing it I am not getting what i want instead YCM start showing me Protected variables and functions in suggestion list.

So question is how to get support for built in function for PHP and avoid protected functions and vars.

Comment: but i want to use vim and i know it is possible in vim.

Comment: No, you want it to be possible, big difference. YCM does nothing special for PHP and all the completion work is done by the default phpcomplete or the custom one. If you don't get what you want with `<C-x><C-o>` then you can't have it.

Comment: Yes you are right. YCM and phpcomplete can perform auto completion individually but YCM not showing for php built function and phpcomplete start showing protected functions of class. and YCM is much better than phpcomplete.

Comment: No. YCM and phpcomplete are *very* different scripts and one can't be better than the other. Whatever suggestion you get from YCM when editing a php file is either provided by the default phpcomplete, by another one that you installed or by Vim itself if all you get is keyword completion. YCM doesn't do any suggestion by itself: it just uses something else and only provides a high level mechanism and Phpcomplete doesn't do anything automatically. So try with `<C-x><C-o>` first: if you don't get the suggestions you want with phpcomplete you won't get them with YCM either.

Comment: I understand, YCM like a manager and phpcomplete or omnicomplete like real worker. I get autocompletion from YCM and if i press ctrl+space then omni complete start working directly(provide list of built in php functions). I am new to vim and it is awesome. I don't know completion working correctly or not in my setup but i removed phpcomplete and getting what i want. thanks for your comment.